# Using GPU in tensorflow with Intel graphic

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, intel, xpu

This is the problem that I have, I am trying using the gpu in tensorflow. I tried so many things and read so many stackoverflow question-answer no luck yet. So, I use this github rep as a reference and I did everything: https://github.com/intel/intel-extension-for-tensorflow

and in this part I get stuck:
`pip install --upgrade intel-extension-for-tensorflow[xpu]`

Requirement already satisfied: intel-extension-for-tensorflow[xpu] in c:\users\rober\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.0.0.dev1)

WARNING: intel-extension-for-tensorflow 0.0.0.dev1 does not provide the extra 'xpu'

The last thing when I ran this:
 `import tensorflow as tf print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))`

I get an empty array

I started with cuda but later I discovered that if I have intel I shouldn't use the other one and I should stick with the "intel" tensorflow. Any resource is welcome maybe I am lacking some concepts. thanks in advance!

I already update my drive, install Intel® oneAPI Base Toolkit and set their enviromental variables and install tensorflow. I don't know maybe it is possible that my computer just can't use gpu or if there is other problems.
[here is my graphic card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55l1T.png)
I see that I have GPU [task manager GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mDsR.png)

Comment: Very simple, the Intel GPU you have is not supported https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-tensorflow/latest/docs/install/install_for_xpu.html#hardware-requirements You need an ARC GPU.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks! I was hoping I could use gpu, but If it is a hardware problem, I can't do much ;(. I have this all-in-one computer and it is extremely hard to open to put a new graphic card.